# Numpy and Tensorflow : ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scipy

I am trying to pass the values to my neural network using feed_dict in tensorflow while passing the values I am getting the value error as mentioned in the title.

Here is my code :

```
train_scipy.minimize(sess, feed_dict={
        sol_int:f, 
        int_var:int_draw,
        bou_var_1:bou_draw1,
        bou_var_2:bou_draw2,
        bou_var_3:bou_draw3,
        bou_var_4:bou_draw4,
        bou_var_5:bou_draw5,
        bou_var_1_alt:bou_draw1_alt,
        bou_var_2_alt:bou_draw2_alt,
        bou_var_3_alt:bou_draw3_alt,
        bou_var_4_alt:bou_draw4_alt,
        bou_var_5_alt:bou_draw5_alt
    })
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mscopy.py", line 378, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "mscopy.py", line 369, in main
    bou_var_5_alt:bou_draw5_alt
  File "/home/jbrahmbhatt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/external_optimizer.py", line 207, in minimize
    optimizer_kwargs=self.optimizer_kwargs)
  File "/home/jbrahmbhatt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/external_optimizer.py", line 402, in _minimize
    result = scipy.optimize.minimize(*minimize_args, **minimize_kwargs)
  File "/home/jbrahmbhatt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 595, in minimize
    return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "/home/jbrahmbhatt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 990, in _minimize_bfgs
    old_fval, old_old_fval, amin=1e-100, amax=1e100)
  File "/home/jbrahmbhatt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 810, in _line_search_wolfe12
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/jbrahmbhatt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py", line 101, in line_search_wolfe1
    c1=c1, c2=c2, amax=amax, amin=amin, xtol=xtol)
  File "/home/jbrahmbhatt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py", line 155, in scalar_search_wolfe1
    alpha1 = min(1.0, 1.01*2*(phi0 - old_phi0)/derphi0)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

As code is way big I cannot put more stuff but I can provide other details if needed I am not sure what is going wrong up here. I am fetching the values from the .csv file and passing it to the optimizer.

Comment: The error is deep inside tensorflow calling scipy.  Looks like it's trying to take python `min` on scalar values, but instead it has gotten array(s).  So some argument or return value is an array when it should be a scalar (single value)

Comment: Oh, what should I do to find that out I have so many variables any way I can find it out which variable raising that error.

Comment: From error stack trace ,   line 369, in main bou_var_5_alt:bou_draw5_alt  .   I think you are using Tensorflow 1.x version with contrib support.

Comment: @TensorflowSupport Yes I am using tensorflow 1.2 do you have any idea what could be done to solve it. Is using contrib support an issue here?

Comment: Hi@JaiminBrahmbhatt !Contrib has been removed from 2.x version.  Can you try with 2.x versions. Please provide simple stand alone code to proceed further!